# bind value without single or double quote in repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, repeater

i have requirement to bind value in repeater itemtemplate without any single or double quote...currently for reference i add html code

```
<div data-thumb=images/banner2.jpg data-src="images/banner2.jpg">
```

above code in my repeater looks like..

```
<div data-thumb="<%#"~/banner/" +Eval("banner_image") %>" data-src='<%#"~/banner/" +Eval("banner_image") %>' data-title="dfdsfds">
```

so i want to bind data-thumb value without single or double quote because u can see the html data-thumb has value without any quote....

Comment: Why do you want this way? AFAIK browser adds the quotes if not provided.

Comment: actually my banners are not working in ie8..so when i remove single quote then it happy with all browsers..

Comment: `data-thumb="images/banner2.jpg"` so you meant to say this is not working when quotes are added.

Comment: exactly...that is not working in ie8..

Comment: Why its not working with "" have u checked your console?

Comment: yes,i have checked my console..but there is no error or warning related that..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can use this alternative m sollution it will work

```
<div data-thumb='<%#"~/banner/" +Eval("banner_image") %>' data-src="@<%#"~/banner/" +Eval("banner_image") %>" data-title="dfdsfds">
```

OR

```
<div data-thumb="@<%#"~/banner/" +Eval("banner_image") %>" data-src="@<%#"~/banner/" +Eval("banner_image") %>" data-title="dfdsfds">
```